# Dynamic templates with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm writing an electron application using materializecss. I want to create a dropdown menu that will show dynamic content from an sqlite database. If I was making a webapp, I'd use handlebars or some similar templating engine. How would you recommend I go about doing this with electron?